# Using routing with faye::WebSocket in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, faye

I am experimenting with websockets in my ruby on Rails server. I am trying [faye-websocket](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) as described in [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets).

Initial tests look promising (I am using a python client and I am able to connect to the websocket) but I have a newbie question that keeps bugging me. Including my websockets library as a middleware in ruby seems to capture ALL requests from my client that are websocket connections. In such case, how do I differentiate (and reply differently) to client calls with different routing (e.g. calls to http://myserver.com/apple and http://myserver.com/pear being both websockets)?

**EDIT**

I found that the env variable contains the field "REQUEST_PATH" which has the information of the routing requested by the client. I can use that variable to return the appropriate answer to each one of the different client calls. Is there any more "elegant" way to do it?

Comment: I'm not a Faye expert, but I'm biased (I'm [plezi.io's](http://www.plezi.io) author, where the websocket is handled in the controller, after the routing)... However: 1. I think you can place the Faye middleware after the Rails request middleware, which will allow you more access to some Rails data. 2. As to writing a router, you can have a look at some routing gems (such as [hanami's](https://github.com/hanami/router)) or copy code from from a router you like. [There are some routing benchmarks here](https://github.com/rack-app/rack-app)

Comment: @Myst thank you very much for the hints. I like your tool very much. I will investigate further on the options you mention.